# What permissions do I need in order to access LinkedIn GET-companiesV2 /search?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use the REST API for searching organizations documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search

but I keep running into the error 'Not enough permissions to access: GET-companiesV2 /search', and the documentation doesn't specify the permissions needed for this specific API

Any idea which permissions do I need and how to acquire them?

Comment: You'll need to apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program (https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products).